# check if a string list contains a substring

Tags: python-3.x, any

I'm having the following codes to test whether string 'h' is in any of the string in list aa. But it's giving me the TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable. Why is that?

```
aa = ['hh', 'ii']
any('h' in aa)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `any('h' in w for w in aa)`

Comment: Thanks @RomanPerekhrest. A further question. What if aa = [['hh', 'ii], ['gg', 'kk']], and I want to find whether 'h' is in any element of the two-dimension list aa? Thanks

Comment: use additional loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `any('h' in aa)` is giving you error exactly as showed in the error message because the conditional returns a boolean which is not an iterable needed for the `any` function input.

```
'h' in aa == False
'h' in ['hh', 'ii'] == False
```

2. You can do this conditional as expressed in the comments using list compreension:

```
any('h' in w for w in aa)
```

3. Furthermore, to use this approach in a list of lists as in:

```
second_list = [['hh', 'ii'], ['gg', 'kk']]
any('h' in value for inner_list in second_list for value in inner_list)
```